# django in product , what are the mandatory services?

Tags: mysql, django, apache, django-admin

I am new to django/apache environment. I am preparing the list of services that are mandatory to get django application running without fail.

I could able to get only two of them in my mind.

1) mysqld -> mysql Daemon.

2) apache2 -> apache daemon.

Could you kindly suggest if any other services required, otherwise the django application fails to run?

Comment: Start here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/

Comment: Brandon, thanks for the reply. I can claim myself that i know how to write simple application from end to end [ urls, views, models, templates]. But in context of requirement of environment, i am very much blind in that. :)

Comment: Your question is too broad. "Mandatory" services are defined by your application. Are you using MySQL? You'll need MySQL Server. Are you deploying with Apache? Gunicorn? There is no "standard"

Comment: @Brandon, No i am not using anything except mod_wsgi apache module.

Comment: Ok, then what exactly are you asking? My suggestion would be to re-phrase your question with some *specifics* about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

you need apache2 mod-wgsi to be installed too:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

and you have to enable apache2 services:

```
$ sudo a2enmod mod-wsgi
```

and disable the default site too
and pass to the apache2 configuration and other

Answer (score 0):

django is a framework; a set of tools that allow you to create web applications - any kind of web application.

There are no list of services required; but if you are asking from a systems management point of view; what is needed to support a *typical* Python web application:

1. You need a WSGI compatible runtime. This can be `mod_wsgi` if you are using Apache; gunicorn or uwsgi.
2. You may need a process manager if you aren't using `mod_wsgi` (whose processes are controlled by Apache).
3. You'll need a web server capable of hosting the static assets for the application. This can be Apache, nginx, lighttpd or any other capable web server.
4. Most applications will also have some sort of database. What database this is, will depend on the application and its requirements (not all features of the django ORM are supported by all databases). So you'll have to check with each individual application. You may choose to provide a "standard" layout; for example MySQL version xx.yy. It could also be that the application is using an external hosted server; in which case your job is just to provide connectivity to the remote hosts.

If you can take care of the above 4, you have a standard layout for host *most* Python WSGI-based web applications.

Keep in mind that although Python 3 has been widely available; most libraries are still in the process of being ported so making sure your server provides both Python 2.7 and Python 3 runtimes is important.

You should also make sure that the development headers for Python (and the database server you are supporting) are available - this is important if the Python application runs in a virtual environment (as this is best practice) since the drivers will need to be compiled for each virtual environment. The same also applies for any compiled libraries (like PIL).

Django has a nice [deployment section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/deployment/) in the documentation to help with specifics.